# Scope of SWF Run id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I would like to know if the RUN ID generated by SWF is unique across the board or is it unique only to a domain + workflow id combination.
Essentially, if I want to store workflow status and other meta data outside of SWF, will it be prudent to key that data off by run id or do I need a composite consisting of domain and workflow id?

Answer (score 2):

According to [SWF API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_StartWorkflowExecution.html#API_StartWorkflowExecution_ResponseSyntax) it is guaranteed to be unique within a *domain*.

> The *runId* of a workflow execution. This Id is generated by the service and can be used to uniquely identify the workflow execution within a *domain*.

So use *domain*, *runId* as your external datastore key.